# link_to with :protocol for https

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code isn't generating https links like I expected it to

```
 <%= link_to 'view your task', project_task_path(@project, @project.tasks, :protocol => 'https')  %>
```

Note that this is pointing to a nested resource.

Comment: you need to pass a specific task like @project.tasks.first , how could you pass @project.tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argh, I have to change

```
project_task_path
```

to

```
project_task_url
```

Apparently path helpers don't support :protocol

Comment: A path helper is literally just a path (Everything after the TLD), you can't change the protocol or domain. If you need to change domains or protocols you have to use the URL helper.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
<%= link_to 'view your task', project_task_path(@project, @project.tasks),  :protocol => 'https'  %>
```