# Make rails url_helpers use https in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I use Rails *url_helpers* to build resources urls in my app. 
An example of a url in development is `http://localhost:3000/resource/1`, generated by the `resource_url(resource)` *url_helper*.

I use nginx in production to *proxy_pass* the requests to my rails app. My nginx listens on port 433 https and redirects to my rails app on port 5000 http:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name     api.staging.zup.me;

  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/cert.key;

  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass      http://localhost:5000;
  }
}
```

Because the request that my Rails app receives from the nginx proxy is **http**, it is generating the urls like, `http://example.com/resource/1`, but only in production I want all my urls to use **https**, for example, `https://example.com/resource/1`.

What is the best way to make Rails generate urls with the **https** protocol only in production?

Comment: possible duplicate of [link\_to with :protocol for https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766833/link-to-with-protocol-for-https)

Answer (score 1):

You can use redirect in nginx and never touch rails app to enable https:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name myserver.domain;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;  # enforce https
}

# HTTPS server
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name myserver.domain;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/myserver.domain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myserver.domain.key;

  root /srv/www/myserver;
  ...
}
```

Not sure if it's a best way, but I like it becuase you don't have to do anything with rails app, only nginx.

Comment: My problem is not the ssl configuration, but Rails url generation. I edited the question to make it clearer.